# How Can i capture a screenshot from Video and Game which use SurfaceView in android?

Tags: android, screenshot, surfaceview

if an Activity have Surfaceview, my screenshot will be black in the Surfaceview area, how can i fix it ? thanks .

Comment: This does not seem to be about programming, could you be more specific about how this is affecting your development process?

Answer (score 0):

Well for that you need to do is get the rootview and save the bitmap drawing cache.

```
View v= getRootView();
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
v.layout(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

v.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap =v.getDrawingCache();


File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/game_screen.png";);
try
{
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream output= new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
    output.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Try this.

Comment: if an Activity have Surfaceview, my screenshot will be black in the Surfaceview area. your sulotion will work correctly when the activity have not Surfaceview. Thanks.